# How to use before_action methods of Pundit in rails grape api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api, ruby-grape, pundit

I'm mounting Grape in my Rails project to build a RESTful API.

Web applications application controller runs `verify_authorized` after every action.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  after_action :verify_authorized,
           except: :index,
           unless: :devise_controller?
end
```

How we can use same `after_action :verify_authorized` in grape `defaults.rb`

I tried by including Pundit in defaults.rb and added method as

```
module Defaults
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include Pundit
  before { verify_authorized }
end
```

But it throws undefined method error.

Can anyone please suggest how to call `verify_authorized` method of `Pundit gem` after every API call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Kukunin/19e4cd9061ca698d132aa9818a2f743b

Comment: thanks @ArupRakshit for reply, i tried this before posting question but didn't helped.

Comment: call the `authorize` method explicitly in your each api action method. It is not a bad idea either.. Grape doesn't have all Rails sugars..